# How do I find the variance of this expression?

Tags: variance

So I need to find the variance where $\gamma_0, \gamma_1,\delta_0,\delta_1$ are constants and $E(u) = 0,$ $E(\eta) = 0,$ $Var(u) = \sigma_u^2,$ $Var(\eta) = \sigma_\eta^2,$ $Cov(u,\eta) = 0.$

$$
Var(q) = Var(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1(\frac{\gamma_0-\delta_0}{\delta_1-\gamma_1} + \frac{u-\eta}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}) +u)
$$

This is a bit of a beast and was wondering if someone could walk me through this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fact that the variance of a constant is zero and the variance of a sum is the sum of the covariances.  Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
Var(q) &=& Var\left(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1(\frac{\gamma_0-\delta_0}{\delta_1-\gamma_1} + \frac{u-\eta}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}) +u\right) \\ 
&=& Var\left(\gamma_0 + \frac{\gamma_1\left(\gamma_0-\delta_0\right)}{\delta_1-\gamma_1} +u \frac{\delta_{1}}{\delta_1-\gamma_1} - \eta \frac{\gamma_1}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right) \\
&=& Var\left(u \frac{\delta_{1}}{\delta_1-\gamma_1} - \eta \frac{\gamma_1}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{\delta_{1}}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right)^2 Var(u) + \left(\frac{\gamma_1}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right)^2 Var(\eta) -2 \frac{\delta_1 \gamma_1}{\left(\delta_1-\gamma_1\right)^2} Cov(u,\eta) \\
&=& \left(\frac{\delta_{1}}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right)^2 \sigma_u^2 + \left(\frac{\gamma_1}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}\right)^2 \sigma_{\eta}^2 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you! I got the same result but my professor skipped a lot of steps in class and actually incorrectly derived this result so I just needed some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified expression:

$$E(q) = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1\frac{\gamma_0 - \delta_0}{\delta_1 - \gamma_1}$$

$$Var(q) = E(q - E(q))^2$$

$$Var(q) = E(\gamma_1\frac{u-\eta}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}+u)^2$$
$$Var(q)=E(\gamma_1^2\frac{(u-\eta)^2}{(\delta_1-\gamma_1)^2} + u^2 + \gamma_1\frac{u-\eta}{\delta_1-\gamma_1}u)$$

This expression can be evaluated if you know $E(u^2), E(\eta^2)$ and $E(u\eta)$.